# Kendo grid datasource nested and combined filters

Tags: filter, kendo-grid

I have multiple filters that I am going to apply on the kendo grid datasource.

If I have a filter like below, everything is okay where **gridConfig** is the configuration of my kendo grid:

```
            var mainFilters = [];

            mainFilters.push({
                field: "x",
                operator: "eq",
                value: 1
            });

            mainFilters.push({
                field: "y",
                operator: "eq",
                value: 2
            });

            gridConfig.instance.dataSource.filter({
                 logic: "and",
                 filters: mainFilters
            });
```

My problem is in here. I have another property lets say **z** that is an array of values. I want to filter the kendo grid datasource on z propery values with **OR** logic. For example, here is my z propery filter:

```
            zFilters.push(
                    { field: "z", operator: "eq", value: 3},
                    { field: "z", operator: "eq", value: 4});

            gridConfig.instance.dataSource.filter({
                 logic: "or",
                 filters: zFilters
            });
```

Now, I want to combine these two filters and apply them simultaneously on my kendo grid datasource. It means that my final result is based on this logic:

```
(x = 1) AND (y = 2) AND (z = 3 OR z = 4)
```

How can I do this with kendo filters?

Answer (score 4):

All sub-filters have to be in an array! This will work:

```
grid.dataSource.filter(
    {
        logic: "and",
        filters: [
            {
                filters:[{ field: "x", operator: "eq", value: 1 }]
            },
            {
                filters:[{ field: "y", operator: "eq", value: 2 }]
            },
            {
                logic: "or",
                filters:[
                    { field: "z", operator: "eq", value: 3},
                    { field: "z", operator: "eq", value: 4}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The structure it has to be in to be applied to a widget if you have mixed 'or' and 'and' filters is

```
 {
   logic: "and",
   filters: [
      { field: "x", operator: "eq", value: 1},
      { field: "y", operator: "eq", value: 2},
      { logic: "or", filters: [{ field: "z", operator: "eq",value: 3 }, { field: "z", operator: "eq",value: 4 }]}
   ]   
 }
```

finally

```
grid.dataSource.filter(abovefilterobject)
```

hope it helps

Comment: I have already tested such structure, however, it does not work. In fact, I have a datasource of kendo grid that I am going to filter it locally.